# Which datatype for generated @Id in hibernate and postgres?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Which datatype should be used if a generated ID is required?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long/Lang/int/Integer id;
```

Which one should/could be prefered, and why?

Comment: From the code I encountered, people mostly prefer `long`. But yeah.. "primarily opinion based question".

Comment: I prefer the non primitive Long as it allows null to demonstrate an entity that has not yet been persisted and removes autoboxing

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `long` for id field compare to `int/Integer` that will cause for huge data to maintain. But if we come to point about `long` and `Long` then it depends on your need each having some benefits along with some loss.

Like if you want to assign null to id then you need to use Long because can't assign null to long primitive or if you using the `long` primitive then it include conciseness and efficiency in your code.

Both `long` and `Long` can be interchange via autoboxing easily. 
So personally I would suggest you that if you using generic code then go with Long other wise no need to create overhead just go with `long`.